# Sending an action from within a socket.io event in a saga

Tags: react-native, socket.io, redux-saga

I am trying to make my login flow work using socket.io and redux-saga.

There is no problem making the socket connection and validating the user, but when I try to dispatch an action from the "loginSuccess"-event, nothing is happening

The login saga looks like this:

```
import { takeLatest, call, put, take } from "redux-saga/effects";
import * as types from "../actions/types";
import connect from "../constants/socketConnection";

function* doLogin(action) {
        const socket = yield call(connect);
        socket.emit("login", {
            username: action.username,
            password: action.password
        });
        socket.on("loginSuccess", (response) => {
            yield put({type: types.SET_CURRENT_USER, currentUser: response.user})
        });
}

export function* login() {
    yield takeLatest(types.LOGIN, doLogin);
}
```

Is it not possible to send an action from within a socket.on()?
The syntax is correct (it works in my other projects), but VS code says that the "put" and "response" are never used and Prettier cannot auto format when the put is there, so it is not registered. No errors are showing though.

Comment: You can't use yield in non-generator function (like your loginSuccess callback). You should use eventChannel instead https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/

Comment: Great, thanks. I made it work.